# implementar react-select

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm

!Saludos!
Como puedo usar react-select, tengo mis items en un archivo aparte es un eccomerce y quiero usar .map(), para traer esos productos y en el select de react, lo que quiero es tener un placeHolder, y que salga mis items, al dar click y que los puedan agregar al carrito, pero el problema que tengo es que al darle click a agregar al carrito y le doy click al carrito para ver los productos me los muestra, pero el precio de los productos esta mal, me explico mis items cada uno tiene 3 precios diferentes pero usan la misma id osea que me debe de mostrar los productos imprimidos separados con sus respectivos precios y lo hace pero el precio siempre lo pone como si estuviera fijo el precio en la posicion 0, puse partes del codigo para que tengan mejor idea, agradezco su ayuda.

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { CartContext, Producto } from "./CartContextProvider";
import Select from "react-select";
const ProductMapped = () => {
const cartContext = useContext(CartContext);
const { productos, handleSeleccion, handleAgregarCarrito } = cartContext;
const handleOptionChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
const productid = parseInt(event.target.value);
handleSeleccion(productid, event);
};
if (!cartContext) {
return <div>Error: No se encontró el producto en el carrito.</div>;
}
return (
<>
{productos.map((producto: Producto) => {
const options = producto.precio.map((precio) => ({
precio: producto.precio[0].precio,
value: precio.id,
label: `${producto.nombre} $${precio.precio}`,
}));
return (
<div key={producto.id} className="prod">
<img src={producto.img} alt={producto.nombre} />
<h3>{producto.nombre}</h3>
<div className="prod-text">
<p>{producto.descripcion}</p>
</div>
<div className="select-container">
<Select
classNamePrefix={"select-content"}
className="select"
options={options}
onChange={handleOptionChange}
placeholder="Escoja una opción"
/>
<div>
<button
className="btn-carrito-tienda"
onClick={() => {
handleAgregarCarrito(producto.id);
}}
>
Agregar al carrito
</button>
```

[{

```
"resource": "/c:/Users/juanq/source/Programacion/React Proyect/vimar/src/components/ProductMapped.tsx",
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "2322",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Type '{ classNamePrefix: string; className: string; options: { value: number; label: string; }[]; onChange: (selectedOption: any) => void; placeholder: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<Pick<Props<{ value: number; label: string; }, false, GroupBase<{ value: number; label: string; }>>, \"value\" | \"form\" | ... 28 more ... | \"theme\"> & InexactPartial<...> & InexactPartial<...>, StateManagedPropKeys> & Partial<...> & StateManagerAdditionalProps<...> & RefAttributes<...>'.\n  Property 'onChange' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<Pick<Props<{ value: number; label: string; }, false, GroupBase<{ value: number; label: string; }>>, \"value\" | \"form\" | ... 28 more ... | \"theme\"> & InexactPartial<...> & InexactPartial<...>, StateManagedPropKeys> & Partial<...> & StateManagerAdditionalProps<...> & RefAttributes<...>'.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 57,
    "startColumn": 23,
    "endLineNumber": 57,
    "endColumn": 31
}]
```